How far away is $\operatorname{SL}_2(3)$ from being quasisimple?
Definition: A group $G$ is quasisimple if it is perfect (i.e., $G=[G,G]$, its derived subgroup) and $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ is simple.
NB: I know that $\operatorname{Inn}(G)\cong G/Z(G)$.
The Question:

How far away is $\operatorname{SL}_2(3)$ from being quasisimple?

Context:
Let $G=\operatorname{SL}_2(3)$.
I know that:

$\operatorname{SL}_2(q)$ is quasisimple for $q\ge 4$.
$Z(G)\cong\Bbb Z_2$.
$\operatorname{Inn}(G)\cong A_4$.
$[G,G]\cong Q_8$.
All subgroups of $Q_8$ are normal; four are both proper and nontrivial.

Clarification:
What I mean by "far away" is something qualitative, hence the soft-question tag. What metrics can we employ to make the question precise? I don't know.
If you could shed some light on how this influences $\operatorname{SL}_2(3)$'s normally generating${}^\dagger$ subsets, then I will be particularly grateful and will likely award a bounty.

$\dagger$: Definition: A subset $S$ of a group $G$ normally generates if
$$\langle\langle S\rangle\rangle_G:=\bigcap_{H\unlhd G\\ S\subseteq H}H=G.$$

I don't know whether this helps, but ${\rm SL}(2,3)$ is normally generated by a subset $S$ if and only if $S \not\subseteq [G,G]  \cong Q_8$, whereas a quasisimple group $G$ is normally generated by a subset $S$ if and only is $S \not\subseteq Z(G)$. But from another perspective, ${\rm SL}(2,q)$ is solvable, which makes it a long way from being quasisimple.

That's interesting, @DerekHolt. Thank you! So what would be the minimal normally generating subsets of $\operatorname{SL}_2(3)$? In my context, it makes sense to look at those in particular.

Let $Q$ be the Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G=\operatorname{SL}_2(3)$ ($Q=[G,G]$). If $a\in G\setminus Q$, then the set ${a}$ is a normally generating set of $G$. The converse is also true. Isn't it? There are no other minimal normally generating sets.
